# How to get the sum of a key of consecutive array object and remove the duplicates?

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6, javascript-objects

I have a main array -

```
const arr = [
    {  description: 'Senior', amount: 50 },
    {  description: 'Senior', amount: 50 },
    {  description: 'Adult', amount: 75 },
    {  description: 'Adult', amount: 35 },
    {  description: 'Infant', amount: 25 },
    {  description: 'Senior', amount: 150 }
]
```

I want help with an es6 operation which will add the amount based on the key(description) and remove the duplicates.

Result array will somewhat look like -

```
const newArr = [
        {  description: 'Senior', amount: 100 },
        {  description: 'Adult', amount: 110 },
        {  description: 'Infant', amount: 25 },
        {  description: 'Senior', amount: 150 }
]
```

Please note, the grouping will be done only on consecutive objects with similar key.

I have been using the reduce operator to achieve this using the solution, but that removes the non-consecutive objects as well.

It would be really helpful if someone can help me with some es6 operators to perform the same operation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

this way

```js
const arr = 
  [ { description: 'Senior', amount:  50 } 
  , { description: 'Senior', amount:  50 } 
  , { description: 'Adult',  amount:  75 } 
  , { description: 'Adult',  amount:  35 } 
  , { description: 'Infant', amount:  25 } 
  , { description: 'Senior', amount: 150 } 
  ] 

const newArr = 
  arr.reduce((res,{description,amount},i,{[i-1]:prev})=>
    {
    if (!prev || description != prev.description )
      res.push({description,amount})
    else
      res[res.length-1].amount += amount
    return res
    },[])

console.log( newArr )
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100%!important;top:0 }
```

Comment: This solution removes the 6th element of the array as well. I want to remove/group only the consecutive objects.

Comment: @AritraGanguly updated...